# How to display the contents of a class which is generic list, by foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach

I want to display the contents of collection in list by foreach loop but variables (name) and (age) do not match in foreach loop.

```
string name;
float age;
List<universe> collection = new List<universe>();
universe main = new universe();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("name");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("age");
    age = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    main.Galaxy(name, age);
    collection.Add(main);
}
foreach (universe b in collection) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(main.Galaxy(name, age));
}
```

I've tried to make a list of (main) but I coudn't.

Comment: What does "not match" mean?

Comment: Your code as written does not make sense. There probably is a small thing to fix and then it all comes together but we don't know what you *want* to do, we only see your code. Could you explain, in plain English, what you *want* your code to do?

Comment: If I understand what you mean by "not match" it is because you execute the `for` loop 10 times then you go to the `foreach` loop where you use the last value for `name` and `age`.

Comment: You are adding the same object 10 times. Move `main` inside the loop. And in `foreach` call `b.Galaxy`, not `main.Galaxy`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
string name;
float age;
List<universe> collection = new List<universe>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    universe main = new universe();

    Console.WriteLine("name");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("age");
    age = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    main.Galaxy(name, age);
    collection.Add(main);
}

foreach (universe b in collection) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{b.Name} {b.Age}"); // <== I don't know if universe class has Name and Age properties
}
```

Comment: Universe class does not have properties it has just 2 arguments (name , age) in it.and I wrote your code but in foreach loop it says "Use of unassigned local variable name and age".

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name;
        float age;
        List<universe> collection = new List<universe>();
        universe main = new universe();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("name");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("age");
            age = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            main.Galaxy(name, age);
            collection.Add(main);
        }
        foreach (universe b in collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("name =" + b.Name + " Age=" + b.Age);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```